# how to install a driver on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers

hey I'm taking to install a Linux driver for my USB wireless adapter(TP-link archer T4u). But I new to Ubuntu and have no idea how to do that and have no internet connect until I do. I downloaded the driver as a zip file but is as far as I got. Can anyone help me through the steps please? also I do not know how to use the terminal.

Comment: What's in the zip?

Comment: Just looking at the instructions. You are definitely going to have to use terminal for this. Are you ok with that?

Comment: Can you mention what files are inside the zip folder?

Comment: I'm ok with using terminal, link is here( http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T4U.html#Driver) trying to install the Linux driver.

Comment: It would take a sec to write up complete, step-by-step instructions with that driver, and I don;t have that device to test...Perhaps first of all what does `$sudo lshw | less` (type that into the terminal with your password and use space bar to page through) tell you for the chipset for the device?

Comment: when inputting that command it asks for user password but wouldn't allow me to input one.

Comment: It just does not echo back... just type it and hit enter.

Comment: when just pressing enter it returns "%sorry, try again" I pressed enter again this time quickly typing my password in the next line it returns "mypassword bash: fg: mypassword: no such job".

Comment: just close the window and start over. with `$sudo lshw | less` and enter your password

Comment: it returns the same response as previously commented also still unable to input password.

Comment: then you are not entering the correct password? (do not enter the $ if you are doing that it is intended to show your prompt).

Comment: in the terminal after refreshing I type "sudo 1shw | less mypassword" it responds "[sudo] password for username: mypassword: No such file or directory"

Comment: 1. Leave away the `$`, 2. it's `lshw` (lowercase L), not `1shw`. 3. Press enter after entering the command, enter your passwd, then hit enter again.

Comment: Btw. the zip contains a **very** detailed instruction.

Comment: ok refreshing and retyping "(not including $)sudo lshw(lowercase L) | less " it response "[sudo] password for username:(did not know that it doesn't display the password so i typed my password then pressed enter)" a few seconds passed it respond with the information about my computer.

Comment: Please run the command: `lsusb` That is a lower-case L; not a one. Pick out the data relevant to your USB wireless device and edit your question to include it.

Comment: when typing that lsusb command it gave me many buses